# Create an alembic migration to create schema for version_table_schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, database-schema, alembic

I want to use alembic to manage my database in the scope of a single PostgreSQL schema named `foo`.
For automatic deployment of new environments I want alembic to create the schema:

```
op.execute("create schema foo")
```

I also want to have the alembic_version table in this schema using `version_table_schema='foo'` for [`context.configure`](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/runtime.html#alembic.runtime.environment.EnvironmentContext.configure) in `env.py`.
However I run into a bit of a catch 22 situation as the schema is not yet created and alembic cant check what version its in.

Is there no way to use the `version_table_schema` kwarg without manual intervention? do i need to have a separate `env.py` and versions folder to create the schema?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can create the schema in env.py like this:

```
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            include_schemas=True,
            version_table_schema='foo'
        )

        connection.execute('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS foo')

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
```

Comment: Helpful but this only works with 'online' mode. If I wanted to generate the SQL script with `alembic revision update head --sql`, I would need to manually ensure the schema exists before running the script.

Comment: I had to use the following code to make it work: `connection.execute(CreateSchema('alembic', if_not_exists=True))`

And the schema is imported like this: `from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateSchema`